# how to change look and feel of JasperViewer?

Tags: java, jframe, jasper-reports

I use JasperViewer to display my report but the look and feel is not i want.

Is there a way to change the look and feel of the JasperViewer?

For example if you click on save button i want to have look and feel of windows or the same things for print dialog when clicking on the print button.

```
JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer(mainPrint,false); 
//viewer.changeLookAndFeel();
viewer.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just before staring of JasperViewer change the look and feel as below.

```
try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer(mainPrint,false); 
            viewer.setVisible(true);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```